# "myths to the contrary notwithstanding"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*This book is based upon a recognition, **myths to the contrary notwithstanding**, that judical processes do not take place in a social void; that judges are men, not gods; that strict observance of legal forms does not necessary assure the accused of a fair trial; and that judges and court systems are themselves judged by the society they are designed to serve.*

Source: https://books.google.cz/books?id=-Gt9BgAAQBAJ&pg=PR11&lpg=PR11&dq=How+this+situation+arose+the+present+volume+graphically+sets+forth,&source=bl&ots=v2jfwNQjbd&sig=S8Z3HrGxT7RidIHK4WbqtWYfyp4&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=How%20this%20situation%20arose%20the%20present%20volume%20graphically%20sets%20forth%2C&f=false

I would like to ask about the phrase "to the myths contrary notwithstanding". Is this a form of the concession? Is not the usage "the contrary" and "notwithstanding" a little bit redundant. The boths terms mean the same after all. Os is it because the phrase shall emphasize the contrast of facts in a statement?

Comment: I wouldn't really say that "to the contrary" and "notwithstanding" mean the same thing, but you could look at it as functioning almost like a double negative: *there are these myths that say the opposite thing, but they don't matter*.

Comment: "to the contrary" modifies myths.   Myths which suggest that judicial process takes place in a void.

Comment: The *chupacabra* is good with children and makes a great pet, myths to the contrary notwithstanding.

Comment: I am not running for president, {reports to the contrary} notwithstanding.  That is, reports which have claimed the opposite, that I am running for president.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[notwithstanding](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/notwithstanding) simply means **despite**, but it's a bit more flexible with positioning. All of these have the same meaning:

> This book is based upon a recognition, myths to the contrary **notwithstanding**, that judical processes do not take place in a void
>
> This book is based upon a recognition, **notwithstanding** myths to the contrary, that judical processes  do not take place in a void
>
> This book is based upon a recognition, **despite** myths to the contrary, that judical processes do not take place in a void

a [myth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/myth) in this context is a **false idea**.

[to the contrary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contrary?q=to%20the%20contrary) means **saying or showing the opposite**.

Putting that all together, we have...

> This book is based upon a recognition, **despite false ideas saying or showing the opposite**, that judical processes do not take place in a void